# AppCode and swift - No warning indication on AppCode

Tags: xcode, xcode7, appcode

I'm not sure why but I'm not getting warning indication on AppCode - similar to the ones you get when using Xcode e.g. when a variable is declared but not used or even type errors.

Is there something I need to do to get it to work.

Here is an screen shot of the same function on both IDE's

Xcode:
[image]

AppCode:
[image]

You can see warning indication on Xcode but not on AppCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not yet implemented in current release, but will be delivered in 2016.2 EAP which we plan to start in 2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Double kudos for giving an estimate.

Comment: @breaktop And now it's ready and you [can try it](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2016/06/appcode-starts-2016-2-eap)

Answer (score 3):

**Update** :  After looking into AppCode references, it seems that they have not implemented this feature (showing warnings) in Swift yet. However, you can look for warning using "Inspect Code"